# Get data on date ranges

Tags: sql

Table Structure

```
Id No   Date        Time

0001,   01-05-2009, 040000
0001,   02-05-2009, 020000
0002,   01-05-2009, 060000
0002,   01-05-2009, 180000
```

`Time` and `Date` is `nvarchar`

I want to get the data between:

- Yesterday 030001 to today 030000
- Day before yesterday 0300001 to yesterday 030000

I tried the below mentioned query

```
Select 
    idno, min (time), max (time) 
from 
    table 
where 
    time between 030001 and 030000
```

Nothing displayed in the result because it is taking today time from 03.00 am to 03.01am
Exactly I need today 03.00 am to yesterday 03.01 am

I need the sql query for the above condition

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you change the table's structure? Storing date and time in nvarchar is a bit silly and makes it really hard to query it.... also, what SQL system are you using??

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to sort or filter when your date is in a format like DD-MM-YYYY.   In such a format, 01-01-2009 comes before 02-01-2000 !

So, first convert your date with the long years first, and the short seconds last:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

A query like this can do that:

```
select [id no],
    substring(date,1,2) + '-' + substring(date,4,2) + '-' + 
    substring(date,7,4) + ' ' +
    substring(time,1,2) + ':' + substring(time,3,2) + ':'
    substring(time,5,2) as NormalDate
from YourTable
```

Now you can easily select all rows for a particular timespan:

```
select *
from (
    select [id no],
        substring(date,1,5) + '-' + substring(date,7,4) + ' ' +
        substring(time,1,2) + ':' + substring(time,3,2) + ':'
        substring(time,5,2) as NormalDate
    from YourTable
) sub
where '2009-05-01 03:00:00' < NormalDate
and NormalDate < '2009-05-02 03:00:00'
```